# How to make Jquery to stop form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, yii2

this is my Yii2 form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['id'=>'first-name']) ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'subject') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'phoneNo')->textInput(['id'=>'phone-no']) ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'location') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'body')->textArea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
                ]) ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button','onclick'=>"verifyData()"]) ?>
                </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

this my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function verifyData(e)
        {
            //~ alert("s");return false;
             phno = jQuery("#phone-no").val();
             var pattern = /^\d{10}$/;
                if (pattern.test(phno)) 
                {
                    alert("Your mobile number : " + phno);
                    return true;
                }
            alert("It is not valid mobile number.input 10 digits number!");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

</script>
```

basically what i am trying with script is to check whether the phone no: is 10 digits or not. checking is working flawlessly but even if no is below 10 the form gets submitted. i want to prevent that if condition is false i don't want the form to get submitted. how to achieve this?

Comment: Try this: `'onclick'=>"verifyData();return false;"` but you should use jquery event binding in place of onclick.

Comment: you can use model validation instead of jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your jQuery document ready function:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#contact-form', function(e) {
    if (!verifyData())  {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

When you submit the form, it calls your function, what is first alerts something, and then returns.

If it returns with `false`, then it preventing the form to submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Model:

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
        [['phoneNo'], 'string' 'min' =>10, 'max' => 10], 
        [['phoneNo'], 'integer']     
   ]
}
```

Comment: well i asked for a jquery solution. i have upvoted you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onsubmit` instead of `onclick` event. And return false after calling `e.preventDefault();`